# Filtrar primeiro resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Tem alguma maneira de filtrar no php o primeiro resultado de uma query ?

Exemplo:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teste2 ORDER BY 'id' DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

if (RESULTADO == PRIMEIRO RESULTADO) {
echo "PRIMEIRO - $row[teste]";
}
else {
echo "NÃO É O PRIMEIRO - $row[teste]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Caminho normal - PHP puro:

Maneiras há várias, eis uma bem didática:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teste2 ORDER BY id DESC")
   or die( mysql_error() );

// usei um contador para você poder testar outras linhas em vez da primeira, se quiser.

$contador = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   if ( $contador == 1 ) {
      echo 'PRIMEIRO - '.$row['teste'];
   } else {
      echo 'NÃO É O PRIMEIRO - '.$row['teste'];
   }

   // Aqui, aumentamos o contador a cada linha.
   // Se preferir, tire a linha de baixo e ponha o ++ no $contador do if.
   $contador++ 
}
```

Perceba que a solução é inteiramente resolvida com PHP. Ainda com PHP, se for só a primeira linha diferenciada, há uma alternativa bem mais simples:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teste2 ORDER BY id DESC")
   or die( mysql_error() );

if ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
   echo 'PRIMEIRO - '.$row['teste'];
}

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
   echo 'NÃO É O PRIMEIRO - '.$row['teste'];
}
```

Desta forma, a primeira linha é resolvida no `if`, e se houver mais, o `while` mostra as seguintes.

<sub>Eu poderia ter posto o `while` dentro do `if` para ele não ser usado à toa caso o resultado viesse vazio, mas o ganho seria praticamente nulo, e a perda de legibilidade imensa.</sub>

### Caminho complicado - contando linhas com MySQL:

Se fosse precisar saber em que linha está pelo lado MySQL, poderia-se complicar desta maneira:

```
mysql_query('SET @i = 0'); // inicializamos i
$query = mysql_query('SELECT (@i:=@i+1) AS linha, name FROM teste2 ORDER BY id DESC')
   or die( mysql_error() );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   if ( $row['linha'] == 1 ) {
      echo 'PRIMEIRO - '.$row['teste'];
   } else {
      echo 'NÃO É O PRIMEIRO - '.$row['teste'];
   }
}
```

> Só mostrei esta segunda maneira para dizer que ela existe. Evite-a enquanto não tiver uma necessidade real de contar as linhas do lado do servidor. As soluções com PHP puro são as adequadas, se o problema real for simples como exposto na pergunta.

<sub>Notar que eu mudei algumas coisas na sua sintaxe, que não tem a ver com o problema principal, mas que também atrapalhariam seu resultado.</sub>

Comment: era isso mesmo que eu queria, é tão simples só adicionar uma variável contando, falta de lógica...valew!!!